# How to delete a specific file in a WebServer (Unused File) through TFS without redeploying the webApp. C#, .Net

Tags: c#, tfs, release-management

In a WebServer (Production) that has a lot of web Application deployed to it, We have one Web App that has an unused file, may deployed incorrectly inside. Since its Prod, unable to delete it directly. have to do it through Release Agent, without redeploying files or scripts. Is there an option ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Since its Prod, unable to delete it directly.` As I understand, seems this means the production is used by customers. And you want to dynamically delete that file without influence the usage of customers.

This could not be achieved for now. You have to do this either during the maintenance of your Production or next release  on the deployment. Redeploying without that specific file will not auto delete  that file. You could use a powershell script or manually delete it directly.